# Need to display Videos and images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

Need to display Videos  and images in UICollectionView.

How to display number of Videos and images in UICollectionView. I am using JSON for download assets from server.

Below is the code for download images from server :

```
NSDictionary *dictImage = [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictImage objectForKey:@“imgURL"]]]; 
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {        
    [cell.imgGallery setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];    
}];
```

Here is the example link for this screen.

[image: Like Whatsapp]

Answer (score 6):

Personally here, I would not load the actual videos into a player in the cell. You should generate thumbnail images and use these with a play icon over the top.

Then when a user selects the video cell, you can present the video player over the top of the collection view.

There is a limit to the number of active AVPlayers you can use at one time and they would consume alot more memory and resources. Scrolling through a large list of cells containing AVPlayers would really slow down cell rendering and eventually would likely crash your application

Answer (score 0):

Load thumbnail images from `SDWebImage` and on click of play button, play video with any video player.
Be careful when playing videos on cells, remove the previous video before playing the new one.

**SDWebImage usage -**

```
[cell.imgGallery sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL
                 URLWithString:@"image_url"]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Image display, Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) - Asynchronous image downloader.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

For Video display, Get placeHolder image from Video and Put Play icon on that videoImage cell.

```
AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:_videoFileURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
imgViewVideo.image = one;
```

When click on Video open AVVideoPlayer

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
playerViewController.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:_videoFileURL];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[playerViewController.player play];
```